# Add 1 day to every row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a test SQL Server database with data about calls received by a call center. Each call has a timestamp, and in my test database I want to add one day to the timestamp field of each row. I'd like to do this daily using a scheduled job, so that the data continues to look like it's fresh from our application's perspective. What I have so far doesn't seem to perform well, as the process continually gets put into a suspended state. I'm definitely not a SQL guru, and my feeling is that there is probably a much better way to do this. Can someone help me out?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [CallMover]

declare @call_id int
declare @call_time DateTime

BEGIN TRY

select @call_id = MIN (ID) from Call

while @call_id is not null
begin
    select @call_time = TimeStamp from Call where ID = @call_id
    update [dbo].[Call] set TimeStamp = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @call_time)
    select @call_id = MIN (ID) from Call where ID > @call_id
end

COMMIT TRANSACTION [CallMover]

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [CallMover]
END CATCH

GO
```

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: Why don't simple execute **update [dbo].[Call] set TimeStamp = DATEADD(DAY, 1, TimeStamp)** for all rows

Comment: There are around 40,000 rows.

Comment: @jason.venema 40000 doesn't sound many to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query is overly complicated. A single `UPDATE` is all you need.

```
UPDATE Call
  SET Timestamp = DATEADD(day,1,Timestamp)
```

Comment: Yup, that works. Told you I wasn't a SQL guru. Noob would be a much better term. Thanks, all.